# Outward Pointing Normal Vector in a Surface Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If we're calculating a surface integral and do a parametrization by parametrizing the surface with some $\vec{r}(u,v)$, how do we know whether $\vec{r}_u\times\vec{r}_v$ or $\vec{r}_v\times\vec{r}_u$ gives the outward pointing normal vector?

Comment: Plug in a test point and see if the vector is pointing the right way

Comment: @NinadMunshi I guess this works, but is there any other way to tell?

Comment: No there is not